# How are the costs for creating Communal Scrolls figured in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

In a thread on the Paizo forums someone asked a question about scroll costs, and what are some of the best scrolls to scribe versus not scribing; and communal scrolls were mentioned.  However another poster threw out the figure of a (x6) scroll cost for communal scrolls.  Is this legitimate?  Where does this figure come from?

Answer (score 6):

The cost of scribing a scroll is always

> 12.5 gp × the level of the spell × the level of the caster. (Core, p552).

**Whether the spell is Communal or not does not matter**, except in that a communal spell is usually one level higher.

I imagine that the person was talking about a specific spell. The spells *ant haul* (Advanced Player's Guide p202), *endure elements*(Core p277), *mask dwemer* (Advanced Player's Guide p232), *mount* (Core p315), *protection from chaos/energy/evil/good/law* (Core p327),  *reinforce armaments* (UC p212), *returning weapon* (UC p214) are all spell level 1 (for at least one class), and have a communal version in **Ultimate Combat** that is spell level 2.

The regular version of each of those spells have caster level 1 as a minimum, so their scrolls would have a minimum cost to scribe of:

> 12.5gp × 1 × 1 = 12.5gp

The communal version of each has a minimum caster level of 3. Since the spell is second level, the communal version would have a minimum cost to scribe of

> 12.5gp × 2 × 3 = 75gp

Which is 6 times the cost of the spell level 1 version. Worth noting is that if the scroll for the regular version is made at a caster level other than 1, or if the difference was not between spell levels 1 and 2, the other poster stops being correct.